# How to register callback with variadic arguments and pass a value

Tags: c++, variadic

could you please help in following.
I have callback function definition in the 3rd lib header:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
typedef int (*SOCK_CLBK)(int, short, unsigned char*, int, ...);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And I define my callback in the following way:

header file:

```
template<typename T>
    int ReadTCP(int socket, short code, unsigned char* msg, int received, T a);
```

cpp file:

```
template<>
    int ReadTCP(int socket, short code, unsigned char* msg, int received, int a)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

and register my callback in the code:

```
server->registerCallback(port, (SOCK_CLBK)(ReadTCP<int>),maxTCPsize);
```

This works fine, and the callback is triggered when needed.

The problem is, the "int a" contains random values every time.
how to register a callback and pass my own specific value for example 100000, that will occur in the callback in "a"?

Something like

```
server->registerCallback(port, (SOCK_CLBK)(&std::bind(ReadTCP<int>,_1,_2,_3,_4, 100000),maxTCPsize);
```

but this does not work (triggers runtime exception).

What I am doing wrong?

lib header:

```
#include "CSocket.h"

#ifndef WIN32
#include <pthread.h>
#else
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinSock.h>
#endif

#define CPP_TCP_MAX_CLIENTS 17
#define CPP_TCP_MAX_SIZE 1500 //In accordance with MTU definitoins

class DLLCPP_API CSERVER {
public:
    /**
     * default constructor
     */
    CSERVER ();
    /**
     * default destructor
     */
    virtual ~CSERVER ();

    /**! \fn int Create(unsigned int uiPort, bool bClbk);
    *   \brief creates singleton socket listener
    *   creates singleton socket listener, which is invoked within dedicated thread
    *   if bClbk is true, otherwise within the main thread.
    *   \param uiPort socket listener port
    *   \param fnClbk call-back function address. if not NULL then callback mode of operation. otherwise normal.
    *   \return 0 on success, error id otherwise.
    */
    int registerCallback(unsigned int uiPort, SOCK_CLBK fnClbk=NULL, int iMsgMaxSize=512)throw (CMException);
….
…
Send()…
….
...

protected:
#ifndef WIN32
    friend void* _fnTCPClbkThread(void *);  //call-back argument for pthread_create within RunClbkThread.
#else
    friend DWORD WINAPI _fnTCPClbkThread( LPVOID lpParam );
#endif

    /**! \fn int IsPending(int iSock, bool& bFail)
     * \brief check pending connection on a non blocking socket
     *  actuall checks for errors and whether or not connection is ready for write operation.
     * \param iSock client socket connection to check.
     * \return: OK (0) if iSock ready for write operation or ERROR otherwise (still pending for instance)
     */
    int IsPending(int iSock)throw (CMException);
    int RunClbkThread();
    int CreateClbk()throw (CMException);
    void ClbkThread();
private:
    typedef void (CSERVER::*PCLBKTHREAD)(void *);
    PCLBKTHREAD _pThreadClbk;
    int     _iServerSock;
    int     _iSock;         
    SOCK_CLBK   _fnClbk;
    unsigned int _uiPort;
    int _iAddrLen;
    bool _bClbkThreadAlive;
    int _iClientConnectionsArr[CPP_TCP_MAX_CLIENTS];
    int _iMsgMaxSize;
    struct sockaddr_in  _saddConnect ;
#ifdef WIN32
    WSADATA m_wsaData;
    HANDLE  _thread;
#else
    pthread_t _thread;
#endif

};
```

Look at function registerCallback
From which I can deduct that the class does not store any user data to be passed later as a callback parameter... Why do they have variadic template then - no idea.

Comment: You need [`va_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_list) to handle C-ellipsis.

Comment: Your template function doesn't match.

Comment: It's not valid to simply cast your function pointer and call it like that. Your callback function needs to be variadic, not just expect an `int` there. Then you need to handle it as a proper C-like variadic function. C++ templated functions are not the same as C variadic functions.

Comment: Avoid C-cast: `(SOCK_CLBK)(..)`. if provided correct function, you won't need cast at all.

Comment: I wrote to the 3rd lib supplier, his answer was: "when serving multiple clients user must save within the call-back ‘struct sockaddr_in’ parameters
in his own storage, then he can use an instance of his own for sending response towards a specific client.

Type definition:
typedef int (*SOCK_CLBK)(int, short, unsigned char*, int, ...);  // variadic template

In this case :
call-back(int sock, short event_id, unsigned char* buffer, int size,  struct sockaddr_in * saddr);
" what could that mean...

Comment: Generally, how to add my own predefined value into the variadic parameter? Later I can read it with va_list, but the question is how to store a value INTO the 3rd lib callback (they provide variadic template for that!!), and not how to read it. IF I do not pass it, va_list will not help.

Comment: Later I will use other data to store in the callback. "int a" is now only used for demo, to understand how it works.

Comment: 3rd library doesn't provide template variadic parameter, just C-ellipsis. I might suppose that according to `event_id` (or from `buffer`), you might know the extra parameters to extract via `va_list`.

Comment: This I did at first, used va_start etc. But when asked the supplier for the parameter list, he answered what I wrote above: when serving multiple clients user must save within the call-back ‘struct sockaddr_in’ parameters in his own storage, then he can use an instance of his own for sending response towards a specific client. Type definition: typedef int (SOCK_CLBK)(int, short, unsigned char, int, ...); // variadic template In this case : call-back(int sock, short event_id, unsigned char* buffer, int size, struct sockaddr_in * saddr); SO he placed sockaddr as an example into variadic params.

Comment: Maybe provide link to the 3rd library used...

Comment: updated the question with the copy from the lib header (the lib itsefl is password protected on the supplier website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code with `ReadTCP` function template is incorrect. `SOCK_CLBK` is a type of a function pointer that has an [ellipsis](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) at the end of its argument list, which is different from `int` (or any other type) that `ReadTCP<int>` has. The compiler does not fail to compile because you explicitly convert the pointer to `ReadTCP<int>` to `SOCK_CLBK`, but the call fails at runtime (you either receive a random value in the `int a` argument or crash).

Your second piece of code with `std::bind` is also wrong because `std::bind` returns a *function object*, not a pointer to function. The function object has `operator()`, so it can be called like a function, but it cannot be converted to a function pointer (for one, because the object also contains data, like the arguments you bound).

You must define a function that accepts a variable number of arguments (i.e. has an ellipsis at the end of its argument list) and pass that function as the callback. In that function, you can process the passed arguments and possibly invoke other specialized functions in your code, like `ReadTCP`.

```
int ReadTCPCallback(int socket, short code, unsigned char* msg, int received, ...)
{
    std::va_list args;
    va_start(args, received);

    // Use variable arguments here, using va_arg. Consult with the API
    // documentation to know what arguments are expected here. For the sake
    // of this example, let's assume an int argument is passed.
    int n = va_arg(args, int);

    int res = ReadTCP(socket, code, msg, received, n);

    // Always call va_end before returning once you're done with va_list
    va_end(args);

    return res;
}
```

If you want to use function objects with this API then you will have to find a way to pass a pointer to data through the third party library to the callback. That data will contain the bound parameters and other state pertinent to the call. Refer to the documentation of that third party library as to how to pass user's data to the callback.

If the API does not support passing user's data (which would make it a rather poorly designed API), you could associate the data with some handle returned by the API that corresponds to your state. For example, you could maintain a global `std::map` to map the socket file descriptor (`int`) to a pointer to your data related to that socket or connection.

Comment: thank you Andrey, now I am sure I did everything fine at the very beginning. I do use std::map with key from Socket, to store tcp client related data. va_list seems to me the only way, to extract the data, and for sure the supplier must provide the API doc about the parameter list. My later experiments (and this question) was triggered by the answer of supplier, about "variadic template", but I guess he himself did not really get what he answered (or did not understand my question). I will mark your post as an Anwer. Thanks!